# Magento back end very slow to open product when lots of prices added

Tags: performance, magento

I'm using Magento 1.7.0.2 and it is all working fine - However I recently needed to upload a large number of customer group prices. As a test run I uploaded the prices for 1 product (400 in total).

The prices uploaded correctly however now when I go into the back end of magento and open the product it takes forever to load - approximately 10 minutes! previously it only took a few seconds. Other items in the catalogue still open in a few seconds. Is there anything I can do to fix this?

The front end of magento seems to perform fine, and I have tried re-indexing the price information to no avail. I have checked the CPU and RAM usage of the server (I should point out that I am the only person using the instance) and the server is never reaching more than 50% capacity for either

Would appreciate any help

thanks

Comment: ohhh man, is there any possibilities to take whole price from the system? Magento is already slow. No good idea, just remove all of them and find an alternate solution!

Comment: thanks for the reply, could you elaborate a little on this please? as previously I have been advised magento can handle large number of prices. Could you suggest an alternative?

Comment: Dear Friend, I will try to investigate and this night then let you know the result.

Comment: lets see which query has performance problem. Turn it on MySQL slow queries parameter then try to view a product again.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, better hosting. Hosting should be 1% of revenue for companies with under $2million per yea. When you start pushing Magneto with large numbers of custom options, many tier prices, you are entering high end sites and need the hosting budget to match, often 200% or more of the 1% revenue until you hit the balance point. The balance point with pushing Magento is often companies with revenue in the $millions, so if you try and do this with a hosting budget in the $100s thousands you will hit a brick wall.

Everything has to be balanced for the store, Google is smarter and know when it is not, so let's say you spend 3mths finding a solution. Google will penalise your ranking anyway, you will have lost 3mths of sales, you will find out that you need that level (unless you are Amazon), and be negative on a return on investment basis that you will not be able to recover the costs. That is why 95% of online stores fail, they basically put themselves out of business before they start.

Can Magento do it, absolutely, the only problem is 99% of the time people do not give it the resources to be able to do its job, and that means 1% of revenue for hosting, and more if you ask it to work like a top enterprise solution.